# EclipseLink and GlassFish: initial DDL creation

Tags: sql, glassfish, eclipselink, ddl, flyway

I try to use Flyway to update my databases. In order to setup Flyway I need to get the current DDL. Normaly one would use EclipseLinks schema generation mechanism by configuring:

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="sql-script" />
```

But I am unable to get this working using a GlassFish 3.1.2.

Is there any possibility to achieve what I want, or am I on the wrong track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glassfish overrides the eclipselink DDL properties for its own DDL generation feature described here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/gbwlh.html
It will force writing out scripts that it then uses to create tables, and drop them if required.  I don't have the location it has them written to, but check if you can control it through glassfish.  Otherwise, try specifying the "eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name" property to define the file name and location it ahold be written to.  You can also access the persistence unit in a simple java main class outside glassfish if you need the script just once and want to store it with the persistence unit.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the first approach is not relay an option because it would manipulate the real database. The second approach is much better.